# How to disable 'awsCodeCommit' on spring boot config server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-codecommit, spring-config

My spring boot config server application was deployed on the AWS server with version 1.3.x and ssh URL is used to clone the repos. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the error I get:

```
org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository - Could not fetch remote for master remote: git@....
```

Comment: What kind of credentials are you using to connect to Git, and how are they configured? This might be a Git credentials configuration issue.

Comment: ssh configuration

Comment: Could you share that configuration (making sure to obfuscate any sensitive data)?

Comment: spring:
  application:
    name: config
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@github.com.......................